# R SPARQL Wikidata: "Opening and ending tag mismatch"

Tags: r, sparql, wikidata-query-service

My aim is to query wikidata using R. I just realized that Wikidata Query Service offers code examples in order to so:

1. Go to https://w.wiki/AkK
2. Execute query
3. Click on </> Code next to the Download button
4. Select R. This gives the following result:

```
#http://www.r-bloggers.com/sparql-with-r-in-less-than-5-minutes/

library(SPARQL) # SPARQL querying package
library(ggplot2)

endpoint <- "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql"
query <- 'SELECT  (COUNT(?item) AS ?count) \n{\n  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146.\n  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }\n} '

qd <- SPARQL(endpoint,query)
df <- qd$results
```

When I run this code the following error message appears: "Opening and ending tag mismatch". The problem seems to be platform independent. What do I need to do in order to avoid getting this error message?

Comment: `qd <- SPARQL(endpoint,query,curl_args=list(useragent=R.version.string))`, https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy

Comment: I suggest you [submit some feedback](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Talk:Wikidata_Query_Service&action=edit&section=new) about this.

Comment: @StanislavKralin your solution works perfectly! If you post your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: FYI: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T226709

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is

`qd <- SPARQL(endpoint,query,curl_args=list(useragent=R.version.string))`